# MP4 video works in ie9, not chrome or safari

Tags: html5-video

I'm creating a site that reads a JSON file and using backbone.js creates a one page website that shows 60 lessons (grouped by topic). Each lesson has at least one video. All videos were encoded in MP4 H.264 and OGG. The site was tested last week in FF, IE9, iPad and iPhone, so I know that the videos were encoded correctly.

Some changes to the host were made and now the videos aren't playing correctly. FF works fine, but the browsers using the MP4 are showing different behaviors.

They actually work in IE9 on the page and surfed to directly.
In chrome, they don’t work on the page but I can surf to the video and it will play.
In safari, surfing to the video doesn’t let it play either.

Here's a link to the site. Ignore the certificate warning. The videos are displayed by clicking the red "WATCH" tab.
https://elearning.rcsdk12.org/courses/Algebra1/#topic/1/lesson/1

Comment: What changes were made to the host?

Comment: renamed the shared folder and the virtual directory in iis

Comment: This link doesn't give a security warning.
https://compass.rcsdk12.org/courses/Algebra1/#topic/8/lesson/1

Now it works in iOS and Safari but not chrome

Comment: Works fine for me in chrome. Does this mean you have fixed it?